# Mysql join showing wrong result in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on PHP with mysql, Right now i have following two tables,And i want to display minimum value according to collection id,Here is my first table "nft_info"

```
id              collection_id           name        
1               18              abc
2               18              xyz
3               19              hax
...
```

And here is my table "nft_sell_info"

```
id              nft_id          listing_price
1               1               15
2               2               50
3               3               30
...
```

Now i want to get minimum value of "listing_price" regarding collection_id='18', I tried with following query but giving me wrong result (showing 50 instead of 15 )

```
SELECT MIN(ns.listing_price) AS lowest_price 
FROM `nft_info` `ni` 
JOIN `nft_sell_info` `ns` 
ON `ns`.`nft_id` = `ni`.`id` 
WHERE `ni`.`collection_id` = '1'
```

Comment: Please add the result too so we can see what wrong result you are seeing.

Comment: there is no `collection_id` of `1` in your data, use `18` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(ns.listing_price) AS lowest_price 
FROM `nft_info` AS `ni` 
JOIN `nft_sell_info` AS `ns` 
ON `ns`.`nft_id` = `ni`.`id` 
WHERE `ni`.`collection_id` = '1'
```

You need to use the AS aliasing throughout your code because the abbreviation isn't working without AS.

Comment: still showing "maximum" value istead of "minimum"

Comment: "listing price" datatype is "varchar" ,if i change to "decimal" then will this work ?

Answer (score 0):

You are query is working [fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/UYaeCVXL) if you change the

`ni`.`collection_id` = '1'

to

```
ni`.`collection_id` = '18'
```

Here is the code I used to test:

```
-- Create nft_info table
CREATE TABLE nft_info (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  collection_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- Insert data into nft_info table
INSERT INTO nft_info (id, collection_id, name)
VALUES (1, 18, 'abc'),
       (2, 18, 'xyz'),
       (3, 19, 'hax');

-- Create nft_sell_info table
CREATE TABLE nft_sell_info (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nft_id INT NOT NULL,
  listing_price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (nft_id) REFERENCES nft_info(id)
);

-- Insert data into nft_sell_info table
INSERT INTO nft_sell_info (id, nft_id, listing_price)
VALUES (1, 1, 15.00),
       (2, 2, 50.00),
       (3, 3, 30.00);

SELECT MIN(ns.listing_price) AS lowest_price 
FROM `nft_info` `ni` 
JOIN `nft_sell_info` `ns` 
ON `ns`.`nft_id` = `ni`.`id` 
WHERE `ni`.`collection_id` = '18'
```

Comment: actually by mistake i typed "1" but still showing maximum value instead of minimum

Comment: @Julia can you check the sql fiddle - it is showing `15`. So, maybe your test data is wrong?

Comment: It is showing 15 for me as well, when I changed the filter value to 18.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(listing_price)
from nft_info t1 
left join nft_sell_info t2 on t1.id = t2.nft_id
where t1.collection_id = 18
```

Comment: I use the same sql, the results are correct.

The listing_price field of the nft_sell_info table is changed to varchar type, and the result is also correct.

Do you still have information to provide?

Comment: SELECT MIN(ns.listing_price) AS lowest_price
from nft_info ni
join nft_sell_info ns
on ns.nft_id = ni.id
where ni.collection_id = 18